# Remap menu key to multitasking

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cyanogenmod, customization, sony-xperia-neo-v

I'd like to remap the physical menu key of my Xperia Neo V running Cyanogenmod 9 to multi-tasking, the way it is on phones that were launched with ICS or Jelly Bean to begin with.

Apps built for ICS would then display the action overflow. With older apps, I guess an on-screen menu key would appear -- I think there is in fact an ICS phone that does this as it has only two keys, but I don't remember the name. Alternatively, the menu key would stay a menu key in these apps but this might be more difficult to achieve.

Is there any way to configure or modify Android to behave this way?

Comment: Just as a point of consideration, on devices that have physical menu buttons [the action overflow button will not appear](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/21657/981). Granted, with CM9 I wouldn't be surprised if someone came up with a way to force it (or something similar), but remapping `menu` might be a little funky.

Comment: My thinking was that if my physical "menu" button is remapped, I don't have a physical menu button any more :)

Comment: It would be kind of interesting to see how Android handled that, as I don't know how precisely it makes the determination that you do (or do not) have a physical `menu` button.

Comment: I'm using HTC Desire which has physical buttons. This awesome [guy](http://www.mattman.org/index.php/downloads2/sandvold-beta-mods) has a patch which displays soft buttons on screen making my phone act as a phone without physical button.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'd want that but it might be good as a starting point for researching where these things are defined.

Comment: So, you want to use a mod that decreases available screen space with no change in functionality?

Comment: Yeah, "I totally want to do that" is exactly what I wanted to say with "I'm not sure if I'd want that".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have just discovered, the latest Cyanogenmod 10 nightlies have this feature. Unfortunately it doesn't ever display an on-screen menu key. As a workaround, I mapped long-press of the menu key to its old function.